# Can I make a struct where more than half of the space is padding?

Tags: c, struct, structure, padding

I'm just beginning learning about padding in struct. So is it right understanding that I could make a struct with only one char (1 byte) and than there is padding of 3 bytes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, a C implementation would not pad a structure containing a single one-byte member. Stricter alignment can be forced with the standard `_Alignas` keyword or other means, in which case the structure could contain more padding than data.

However, we can create normal structures with more padding than data. Consider `struct { char a; double b; char c; }` in a C implementation where `double` is eight bytes and requires eight-byte alignment. To lay out this structure, the implementation must insert (at least) seven bytes of padding between `a` and `b` and must insert (at least) seven more after `c` to make the structure size a multiple of eight bytes (which is needed so that the elements in an array of such structures maintains their required alignments).

This structure has ten bytes of data in its members and fourteen bytes of padding.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, depending on your padding and byte alignment settings.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want this:

```
#pragma pack(push, 4)
struct {
    ...
}
#pragma pack(pop)
```